# Permissions in Discord.js API?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm coding a Discord bot with discord.js/node (I'm fairly new).
I tried to setup a permissions system where you would need a specific role to make an `if` statement return true and allow the user to use a command or something else. I tried (this is just part of it):

```
if(message.author.roles.includes('role_id') {
   COMMANDS
   }
```

But it just gives me errors in the console (obviously)

If any of you know how to *properly* set a permissions system up in a efficient way, that would be appreciated!

Comment: Discord.js ``message.author`` object does not contain a member ``roles``. See: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User

Comment: Yeah I looked through the documentation again and I tried `.member` (which represents the `GuildMember` class that has the `roles` property) instead of `.author`. It still doesn't work though.

Comment: Roles seems like a collection, so you would need to make use of their ``.exists()`` method. I don't think it's an array by default, but don't quote me on it. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=exists

Comment: I did `if(message.member.roles.exists(role_id))` and it crashed, giving me an error.

The documentation said to use `.has()` instead of `.exists()` when checking for item IDs, and `.has()` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this using an `if` conditional: `if(message.member.roles.has(`**`[role_id]`**`))`
where **[role_id]** is a string (otherwise it will always return false)

Answer (score 0):

There is an `hasRole` method on users: http://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/8.2.0/docs_user.html

> hasRole(role)
>
> Shortcut of client.memberHasRole(member, role)
>
> See client.memberHasRole

Which link to this: http://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/8.2.0/docs_client.html#memberhasrole-member-role

> memberHasRole(member, role)
>
> Returns if a user has a role

Comment: That's only the permissions, but I'm looking for if a user has the roles.
Unless there's a way to use an `if` statement with that to check roles with `hasPermission`

Comment: That doesn't work, it just crashes my bot with an error.
Thanks though.
EDIT: Figured out how to do it by permission/role.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing something like this?

```
 if (!message.member.roles.some(r=>["role_name"].includes(r.name)) ) 
    return;
```

This will prevent all users from using that specific command unless they have the specified role.